# Recurring iPhone 13019 error during syncing

Tags: mac, iphone, sync

From time to time, my iPhone 3G (Syncing with Mac OS X 10.6.2, iTunes 9.0.2) starts returning an error (13019) every time it attempts to sync.

This problem can be consistently resolved by switching off music syncing, syncing the phone, and then switching music syncing on again (See http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2830), but then seems to reoccur (on average maybe ever week or so).

Is there any way to identify/resolve/work around whatever the underlying problem causing this issue to reoccur?

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to [uncheck syncing of Voice memos](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=721180) and try syncing again.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that - Hasn't helped unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem, on an off for months.  I tried the old unsync nonsense, and all to no avail.  The Apple website is a bit over the top, http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2830 , when all you might need to do is the following.

1. Make a backup of the iPhone, this is different to sync as it backs up the phone, rather than syncing with known content.  This will also backup all the latest content on the phone should you need to get it back.
2. Delete all Voice Notes on the iPhone.
3. look at iTunes, Voice Notes, under music and manually delete all duplicate entries, for some reason I had Hundreds of them.  (Strange how iTunes could not figure this out.)
4. Resync and all the valid Voice Notes should be resynced with the phone.

This worked for me.